# Wicket - retrieving PageParameters on session level in elegant way

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

I need to retrieve parameter from url. It's a simple case when I do this on WebPage level - it could be done by sth like this:

```
    @MountPath(INDEX_PREFIX + "/${" + OBJECT_ID_KEY + "}")
    public class IndexPage extends WebPage
    {
            public IndexPage(PageParameters parameters)
            {
                    String id = parameters.get(OBJECT_ID_KEY).toString();

                    // etc...
            }
    }
```

But I need it to be done **on session level** - in *getRoles()* method.

I've done this in that way:

```
    @Override
    public Roles getRoles()
    {
            final Request request = RequestCycle.get().getRequest();
            List<String> segments = request.getUrl().getSegments();
            if (segments != null && segments.size() > 1 && INDEX_PREFIX.equals(segments.get(0)))
            {
                    String id = segments.get(1);
            }

            // etc...
    }
```

Url structure looks like this: *www.my.page.com/index/5*

*index* - `INDEX_PREFIX`

*5* - `OBJECT_ID_KEY`

Is there a better way???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the `Request` in your hand - now just follow the API :-)

```
Request req = RequestCycle.get().getRequest();
IRequestParameters params = req.getRequestParameters();
StringValue idValue = params.getParameterValue("id");
```

And there you go.

Comment: I've tried this solution - *idValue* returns null... It works good when I pass arguments like eg: *.../?id=5*, but I need to have it via RESTful Api

Comment: Something like: *www.example.com/index/5*, where 5 is my *id*

Comment: You need to mount your page with a pattern like this, in your application#init(): mountPage(MyPage.class, "/index/${id}");